# How can I induce Term::Readline to set the UTF8 flag one the results from readline?

Tags: perl, utf-8, readline

How can I induce [Term::Readline](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term%3A%3AReadLine) to set the UTF8 flag one the results from `readline`?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings FATAL => qw(all);
use strict;
use 5.10.1;
use utf8;
use open qw( :encoding(UTF-8) :std );
use Term::ReadLine;
use Devel::Peek;

my $term = Term::ReadLine->new( 'test', *STDIN, *STDOUT );
$term->ornaments( 0 );
my $char;

$char = $term->readline( 'Enter char: ' );
Dump $char;

print 'Enter char: ';
$char = <>;
chomp $char;
Dump $char;
```

The output:

```
Enter char: ü                                                                                                                                                                                 
SV = PV(0x11ce4c0) at 0x1090078
REFCNT = 1
FLAGS = (PADMY,POK,pPOK)
PV = 0x14552c0 "\374"\0
CUR = 1
LEN = 16
Enter char: ü
SV = PV(0x11ce4c0) at 0x1090078
REFCNT = 1
FLAGS = (PADMY,POK,pPOK,UTF8)
PV = 0x14552c0 "\303\274"\0 [UTF8 "\x{fc}"]
CUR = 2
LEN = 16
```

Comment:

When I am searching in a `mysql` database (with `mysql_enable_utf8` enabled):

```
my $stmt = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE City REGEXP ?";
say $stmt;

# my $term = Term::ReadLine->new( 'table_watch', *STDIN, *STDOUT );
# $term->ornaments( 0 ); 
# my $arg = $term->readline( 'Enter argument: ' ); # ü -> doesn't find 'München'

print "Enter argument: ";
my $arg = <>; # ü -> finds 'München'
chomp $arg;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why? Those two strings are equivalent. It's like 0 stored as an IV vs stored as a UV.

Well, it's possible that you have to deal with buggy XS code. If that's the case, `utf8::upgrade($s)` and `utf8::downgrade($s)` can be used to change how the string is stored in the scalar.

Unlike encoding and decoding, `utf8::upgrade` and `utf8::downgrade` don't change the string, just how it's stored.

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -E'
   $_="\xFC";
   utf8::downgrade($d=$_); Dump($d);
   utf8::upgrade($u=$_);   Dump($u);
   say $d eq $u ?1:0;
'
SV = PV(0x86875c) at 0x4a9214
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0x8699b4 "\374"\0
  CUR = 1
  LEN = 12
SV = PV(0x868784) at 0x4a8f44
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK,UTF8)
  PV = 0x869d14 "\303\274"\0 [UTF8 "\x{fc}"]
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 12
1
```

Comment: I've written a comment below my question.

Comment: Ah yes, many DBD do indeed suffer from "the Unicode bug". Assuming Term::ReadLine did decode, `utf8::upgrade` is definitely what you want.